# Intermittent Unauthorized Additional claims required errors when calling /user/chats endpoint

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph, microsoft-teams, graph-api

I am experiencing intermittent errors when querying the graph api endpoint for teams chat.
I am using powershell and delegated access.

Here is a code snippet:

```
$tenantId = "my_tenant_id"
$clientId = "my_client_id"
$tokenOutput = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientId -TenantId $tenantId -Interactive
$token = $tokenOutput.AccessToken
$accessToken = ConvertTo-SecureString $token -AsPlainText -Force
```

A call to get the "me" profile works 100% of the time:

```
$members = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me" -Authentication OAuth -Token $accessToken
```

A call to get my chats fails a lot - but NOT ALL - of the time. I am working around it by using the retry switch.

```
$chats = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats" -Authentication OAuth -Token $accessToken

Invoke-RestMethod: {"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Additional claims required {\"access_token\":{\"capolids\":{\"essential\":true,\"values\":[\"some_GUID\",\"some_GUID"]}}}","innerError":{"date":"2023-09-26T16:17:11","request-id":"some_id","client-request-id":"some_id"}}}
```

It seems to be just the chats endpoint that has the issue and I emphasize that it is intermittent.

Does anyone have any insight?

Thanks.

Comment: No-one? Would appreciate any guidance.